# How do I determine if a category exists by ID?

Tags: plugin-development

I know I can get a categories ID by calling get_cat_ID('category-slug'), however, what is the method to call to determine if a category exists by ID when you don't know the slug?

In other words, I need to determine if category id 1 exists. What's the function for this?

Can I just use if(get_category(1)) {//do something?}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [`category_exists()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php#L13) function, but it seems to be for internal use in admin so you can try [`term_exists()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_exists) instead.

Comment: you learn new stuff every day.

Comment: I only need to call it inside of an is_admin() call anyway, in order to set a static variable. Should I use category_exists or term_exists? What if uncategorized (defaults to term_id 1) has been deleted? Does that mean term_exists(1) will always return false? or can term_id 1 be then used for another term item?

Comment: @Scott B `category_exists()` pretty much only calls `term_exists()` with specifying `category` as taxonomy - not much difference which to use. Not sure about reusing IDs, likely they aren't but didn't test it.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [get_term_by](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)

you can define by what you want to look for the term using slug,ID or name
so you can call it like this in your case:

```
    function check_category_exists($catid){
       $cat_to_check = get_term_by( 'id', $catid, 'category')
       if ($cat_to_check){

       return true;
       }
       else{return false;}
    }

//then call it like this:
if (check_category_exists(1)){  //category exsits. }
```